# Where are the shift/reduce conflicts in this Bison code coming from?

Tags: bison

I'm trying to parse this syntax:

```
34 + 1 − 8, 32 * 87 + 6 / 4, 34 / 8
```

I'm expecting to ground it like this:

```
(, (- (+ 34 1) 8) (/ (+ (* 32 87) 6) 4) (/ 34 8))
```

This is the code for BISON:

```
%token NUMBER
%token COMMA
%token OPERATOR
%left OPERATOR
%left COMMA
%%

term: NUMBER | term op term ;
op: OPERATOR | COMMA;
%%
```

There is a problem:

```
test.y: conflicts: 2 shift/reduce
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: You example output doesn't match the input. You're missing the ` / 4`

Comment: If I remember the compilers course correctly, the term operator is not a LL1 grammer. You have to transform it to an LL1 grammer in order to make it work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your definition of `term`:

```
term: NUMBER | term op term ;
```

When parsing this, at each number, the question is: should I read another token to know if I have the first, or the second form.

A solution could be to define:

```
term: NUMBER reminder;
reminder: /* empty */ | op term;
```

The grammar, once adapted, looks like the following:

```
%token NUMBER
%token COMMA
%token OPERATOR
%left OPERATOR
%left COMMA
%%

term: NUMBER reminder;
reminder: /* empty */ | op term;
op: OPERATOR | COMMA;
%%
```

compiles without warnings with `bison (GNU Bison) 2.4.1`.

Comment: This answer has the wrong diagnosis. The problem is actually that the precedence declarations have no effect, because the operators are already reduced to `op`. Since precedence is static, there is no precedence for the `term op term` production, and that production is ambiguous.

Answer (score 13):

To find where the conflicts are, use the `--verbose` option and look at the file `example.output` where your input file is `example.y`. Here is the file I got from your input:

```
State 7 conflicts: 2 shift/reduce
```

*(omitted)*

```
state 7

    2 term: term . op term
    2     | term op term .

    COMMA     shift, and go to state 4
    OPERATOR  shift, and go to state 5

    COMMA     [reduce using rule 2 (term)]
    OPERATOR  [reduce using rule 2 (term)]
    $default  reduce using rule 2 (term)

    op  go to state 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify the priority of the operators like,

```
%left '+' '-'

%left '*' '/'

(in definition section)
```

Which can be the reason.