# How to fix this yacc shift/reduce conflict

Tags: yacc, lex

I have this grammar

```
value
    : INTEGER
    | REAL
    | LEFTBRACKET value RIGHTBRACKET
    | op expression
    | expression binaryop expression
    ;
```

and I am getting this shift reduce error

```
47 expression: value .
53 value: LEFTBRACKET value . RIGHTBRACKET
RIGHTBRACKET  shift, and go to state 123
RIGHTBRACKET  [reduce using rule 47 (expression)]
$default      reduce using rule 47 (expression)`
```

So far I tried setting %left and %right priorities with no luck. I have also tried to use a new grammar for value that does not call itself again but I get conflicts. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264884/where-are-the-shift-reduce-conflicts-in-this-bison-code-coming-from) solution too

any thoughts?

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

```
expression
    : lvalue
    | value
    ;

lvalue
    : IDENTIFIER
    | lvalue LEFTSQBRACKET expression RIGHTSQBRACKET
    | LEFTBRACKET lvalue RIGHTBRACKET

binaryop
    : PLUS
    | MINUS
    | MUL
    | DIVISION
    | DIV
    | MOD
    ;
```

I manage to overcome most of the conflict using this grammar but i still get the conflict i mention above

```
binaryop
    : expression PLUS expression
    | expression MINUS expression
    | expression MUL expression
    | expression DIVISION expression
    | expression DIV expression
    | expression MOD expression
    ;
```

Comment: Use a normal expression grammar, instead of trying to invent your own. Examples abound.

Comment: You are still not using anything I recognize as a standard expression grammar. Such a thing contains productions for expression, term, factor, and primary. I repeat that examples abound. This problem was solved in 1959. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Why do you think you need both `value` and `lvalue`? The term 'lvalue' suggests that you're trying to mimic C, but in C, the difference between r-values and l-values is drawn at semantic level, not in syntax.

Comment: I didn't create the grammar myself. To be more specific i found the grammar in a book. I am just developing the lex-yacc for this grammar

Answer (score 2):

Why do you have both `value` and `expression`? Without seeing the rest of the grammar, I hesitate to guess the use of `expression` which leads to that conflict, but my guess is that it has to do with the unnecessary unit production.

On the other hand, you will not be able to resolve precedences if you lump all operator terminals into`binaryop` (unless all binary operators have the same precedence). So I'd suggest you find a standard expression grammar (such as in the bison manual or wikipedia) and use it as a base.

Comment: I still think you have an excess of non-terminals, but the basic problem, which is fairly well shown in the bison output, is that `( ... )` is ambiguous; when the parser sees the close paren, it has no idea which non-terminal to reduce the enclosed expression to.

Comment: How can i solve the conflict with the parenthesis? Even when i tried to change the grammar a little bit to fix the conflicts with the operators i still get a conflict every time i am using somthin like  LEFTBRACKET ... RIGHTBRACKET

Comment: By not duplicating the production for `(...)`. Why do you feel that is necessary?

Comment: Because the grammar of value says so and i can't find a way to change it without losing it's functionality